# issue with UITableViewStyleGrouped

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have 2 UITableViewControllers, both are using same data source but for some reason one of them has weird header gap on the top. I don't understand why. When I'm changing style to UITableViewStylePlain the positioning is fine but I need grouped style here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please put some code you are using so that others can answer your question

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the header size using [`heightForHeaderInSection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:).

Comment: From the docs: On iPad devices, table views in the grouped style automatically get wider margins when the table views themselves are wide.

Comment: So basically the issue is that TableView with grouped style on iPad device set margins automatically. Does anyone know how to change these automatically set margins?

Comment: Try settings the frame with CGRectMake.